# Should the first letter be capitalised or not in the letter?

Tags: writing

Every example I come across for writing German language letter, starts with a small cased letter, eg.

> ich hoffe es geht dir gut.

But the rules say start the sentence with capitalised letter. Then why not :

> Ich hoffe es geht dir gut.

Can't find what's right ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is because the greeting is part of the first sentence if you put a comma behind it. Which is the default.

> Lieber Amit, ich hoffe, es geht dir gut.

becomes

> Lieber Amit,
>
> ich hoffe, es geht dir gut.

If you use a different punctuation for the greeting, you have to obey that punctuation's rules.

> Lieber Amit!
>
> Ich hoffe, es geht dir gut.